# How to use Java connector for Cassandra to get data from dependent column families

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am looking into Apache Spark, Cassandra 3.7 and Datastax’s Java connector for Cassandra.

This could be completely foolish and naive question for you but I am not getting correct way to handle it from documentation

I have 2 tables

Cassandra Column Family: Seasons

```
+------------------------+
| Id | Season | isActive |
+------------------------+
| 001 | Summer | 0       |
| 002 | Fall   | 0       |
| 003 | Spring | 1       |
+------------------------+
```

Cassandra Column Family: Fruits

```
+---------------------------+
| Season | Fruit Name | Id  |
+---------------------------+
| Summer | Fruit1     | 001 |
| Fall   | Fruit2     | 002 |
| Spring | Fruit3     | 003 |
| Spring | Fruit4     | 004 |
| Summer | Fruit5     | 005 |
+---------------------------+
```

Assume that this Fruits column family is huge so I do not want to load all the data in Spark.

First, I want to get the active seasons, in the above example it is  “Spring” and then get the fruits of that Active season from Fruits table, I am not able to do this using Datastax’s Java connector for Cassandra. This could be simple but I think I am missing something and I would like to get another view on this from you.

Till now I did the following

```
JavaRDD<SeasonsClass> seasons RDD = CassandraJavaUtil.javaFunctions(sc)
            .cassandraTable(“myKeySpaceName”, "Seasons")
            .map(SeasonsClass.getSeasonsRows())
            .filter(SeasonsClass.filterActiveSeasons());

JavaRDD<FruitsClass> fruitsRDD = CassandraJavaUtil.javaFunctions(sc)
            .cassandraTable("myKeySpaceName", "Fruits")
            .map(FruitsClass.getFruits());
```

But this gives me all fruits and not the fruits on active season. How can I get only active season fruits.

I get the list of active seasons but then how can I get the fruits of this active season?

I am using

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0-M1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think this is probably a data modeling issue.  In order to query your Fruits table by season you will want to designate the Season column as your partition key, and Fruit Name as your clustering column.  I don't think you would need the ID field for this set up, but it depends on what you are using that for.

Comment: Hello @gsteiner, my data model is same as you are saying, just my representation is changed in the question. I will correct it. But even after making that change what I want is first get active season from the Seasons CF and then get the Fruits of that active season. How do I achieve that programatically? - Thanks

Comment: Hello @gsteiner, I am not able to build the dynamic way of getting Fruits based on active Season. I want to do it like MySQL, create a dynamic query in advance and then just bind the required input later in the query when required.  But not using queries, I want to use Spark-Cassandra-connector-for-Java. So how to bind the active season with a query on Fruits CF to get fruits of that active season only rather than loading the complete Fruits CF and then filter. Which Java API supports this? Any idea?

Comment: You can do it with the Cassandra Java driver by querying the Seasons table first for the active season, and then querying the fruits table where season = the season you got in the first query.  I'm not sure how to achieve this with the Spark connector, but I'm sure there is a way.  I am just not too familiar with it yet.  I apologize that I did not answer your question.

Comment: Thank you @gsteiner. I will check on the way you suggested.